# WPF ListBoxItem Style Is Overriding My ItemTemplate?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a listbox that is bound to a list `Items` of objects that have two properties: `Name` and `IP`.

I would like to set a tooltip for each item that displays the IP address on hover, so I've done this:

```
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" ToolTip="{Binding IP}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

This works. However, when I apply the following style, it seems that my `<DataTemplate>` is being ignored completely and the list is just calling `ToString()` on my objects and the tooltip never shows up at all.

```
<Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                    <Border x:Name="Bd"
                 Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                 BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                 BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                 Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                 SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <Grid>
                           <GridViewRowPresenter x:Name="gridrowPresenter"
                        Content="{TemplateBinding Property=ContentControl.Content}" />
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter"
                        Content="{TemplateBinding Property=ContentControl.Content}"  Visibility="Collapsed" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="GridView.ColumnCollection" Value="{x:Null}">
                            <Setter TargetName="contentPresenter" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="Control.IsMouseOver"  Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Background" >
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <SolidColorBrush Color="#FFE6E6E6" Opacity="0.75"/>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected"  Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Background" >
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <SolidColorBrush Color="#FFA5C5D1" Opacity="0.75"/>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Why is this style preventing the DataTemplate from being applied?

Comment: Have you tried not binding the ContentPresenter's `Content`? It should work without that by default. Binding it (or using a TemplateBinding) is probably disrupting the default ContentControl functionality. Check the `ListBoxItem` default Template: https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms750821(v=vs.85).aspx ... The `ContentPresenter` is left as-is, and it is the ContentControl logic what makes the rest.

Comment: I just realized you have TWO Presenters (Why??), so you might want to go all the way around then, and not only bind the `Content` property but also bind `ContentTemplate` to your ListBox's ItemsTemplate (which should also be your ListBoxItem's ContentTemplate, I guess)

Comment: You are right. Removing the Content binding from the ContentPresenter did the trick.

Comment: Glad to know :) I'll post it as an answer for anyone that could have the same doubt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried not binding the ContentPresenter's `Content`? It should work without that by default. Binding it (or using a TemplateBinding) is probably disrupting the default ContentControl functionality.

Check the `ListBoxItem` default Template: msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms750821(v=vs.85).aspx

The `ContentPresenter` is left as-is, and it is the ContentControl logic what makes the rest.